# Water through a Copper-Coil Heat-Exchanger: How much tubing will be enough?

Tags: heat-transfer, heating-systems, thermal-conduction, heat-exchanger

I am making a hot-water tank for a boat.  Within it will be a copper-coil heat-exchanger.
Because copper tubing can be rather expensive, I am trying to better understand the design beforehand, and thus better approximate the required length of tubing before buying it.

In the diagram/example below, the barrel-tank is filled with freshwater at a constant (for sake of simplicity) 80+°C.  Another source of water starting at 16°C passes through the coil and is converted to 60°C.

**My question:**
How long should the copper coil be to achieve this effect given the flow-rate of 2.5L/min? (-The copper tubing is 10mm in its outer-diameter, and 1mm thick. -10m of tube will hold approx. 0.50L of water.)

Also, I don't really need absolutely precise answers here. -Just ballpark estimates will suffice.

**If anyone has any comparative examples (videos, links, etc.), that would be very helpful indeed!**

[image: Copper-Coil Heat-Exchanger Diagram, Details, and Question]

### **-Thanks for any info./help!**

Comment: Engineering Heat Transfer by Simonson will have all the equations and explanations you need. But the surface area will be a deciding factor here, and if that means too long a pipe then copper pipe is available with fins - made for solar water heating tanks.